# Splash screen activity which needs to pause when dialog box is open

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I have an splash screen activity which has a timeout of 1000 milliseconds. But then it is displaying certain permission dialogs which need acceptance or rejection from the user, and on completion of 1000 milliseconds the activity changes. So I need to design my splash screen such a way, that the timer stops when permission dialog is being displayed....

Comment: Can you elaborate, coz I am having both permission taking, and timer in oncreate() itself....

Comment: in oncreate(), call runtime permissions after user accepting the permissions it will hit onRequestPermissionsResult. Inside onRequestPermissionsResult you can call timer functionality.

Comment: I have updated my code below. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First call the runtime permission functionality after that call splash screen timer inside the  onRequestPermissionsResult.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    requestPermission();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean camera = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (camera) {
                    // Call Timer
                } else {
                    // Request permission
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if user denies it should open up

Comment: Then call timer funciton in onRequestPermissionsResult. no need any if condition